# How can i get thumbnails of autocad(dwg) files and show them into "asp:image" control?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to write a web base document management system(ASP.NET,C#),now i need to show thumbnails of recived files when users viewing them.Thanks for any solutions...

Answer (score 2):

Try here for starters - http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/10/au-handouts-t-1.html

This is a good AutoCAD programming blog in general. FYI, DWG Trueview is free. I don't know if the COM interface is still accessible but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the software available from the Open Design Alliance.
[Open Design Alliance](http://www.opendwg.org/)

The last time that I was trying to use the DWG TrueView program (connecting to the COM interface) it was pretty flaky, things might have improved.